# Cannot import 'Tk' from 'tkinter'

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm

I'm relatively new to programming and am working a very basic GUI for a filemanager/tree calculator application with PyCharm, however I cannot test my code because of the issue regarding 'Tk'. I cannot use 'Tk' in any of my code as it is either not a tkinter module or cannot be imported from tkinter.

Here is the first bit of my code

```
import tkinter as tk
from future.moves import tkinter
from tkinter import messagebox, Tk


window = tk.Tk()

window.mainloop()


def calculate_trees():
    files = file_count_entry.get()
    trees_saved = int(files) * 0.02
    messagebox.showinfo("Trees Saved", f"You have saved {trees_saved} trees!")
```

Any ideas on solutions/alternatives?
Thanks in advance.

I tried alternatives to the use of 'Tk' but to no avail so far

Comment: Did you name your program file `tkinter.py`, or have some other file with that name in the same folder? What do you get if you do `print(tkinter.__file__)` after the import?

Comment: No, I made sure no other files were named 'tkinter.py'. After putting in 'print(tkinter.__file__) ' after the import I don't have any more issues, but when I add in the rest of my code, I run into the issues regarding not being able to use or import 'Tk'

Comment: What does the `print` statement show? What is the exact error when you try to run your program? FWIW, the program works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try omitting the `import` of `future` model. You don't even use it in the code. It may be overriding the `tkinter` name.

successfully!

Jonathan

Answer (score 0):

As @ylj mentioned, remove `from future.moves import tkinter`. And, since you are using `tk.Tk()` to create a `Tk` object, remove `Tk` from `from tkinter import messagebox, Tk`.

The modified code would be as shown below.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox


window = tk.Tk()

window.mainloop()


def calculate_trees():
    files = file_count_entry.get()
    trees_saved = int(files) * 0.02
    messagebox.showinfo("Trees Saved", f"You have saved {trees_saved} trees!")
```

References on how to import Tkinter and create a window: [Create a Tkinter Window](https://pythonexamples.org/python-tkinter-window-example/), [Python Tkinter tutorial](https://pythonexamples.org/python-tkinter/)

Comment: Thanks for your initial answer, however I now get this error now:
window = tk.Tk()
AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'Tk'. Did you mean: 'tk'?

Which doesn't make much sense as countless YouTube tutorials suggest something similar but for som reason does not work with me